# Using SSH in Raspberry Pi to get Input?

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, ssh, raspberry-pi

I need to run Python scripts from SSH on my Raspberry Pi, while still being able to get input from a user on the Raspberry Pi via a USB keyboard emulator (*card reader*). I would normally be able to use `raw_input` for this, but if I run the Python script through SSH, it does not create a window and it will not be active so it will receive no input.

Is there any way to ensure a Python script will be active (the top window), even while using SSH to launch it? Or, is there another way to get user input without using `raw_input`, and works in the background (without an active window)?

Thanks in advance :)

PS: If I have to use other languages (like C) then invoke it in Python, this is fine, I will be able to do that.

Comment: When using SSH you're executing python script remotely, so you can't get data from raw_input.

Comment: oh, so there is no way to make a new window in python?

Comment: Try this: call a python script from ssh, which will call your python script (one with the window). I'm not if that will work, but give it a try. Both file will be in Pi.

Comment: ok, I'll give that a shot, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it the best I can, with help from @Gaurav Dave

I now have a script which creates a new terminal window upon launch, using `Popen` from `sys`. The script looks like this...

```
from sys import executable
from subprocess import Popen, CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE

Popen([executable, 'window.py'], creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
```

and `window.py` is simply a test script that prints some text and waits for a certain amount of time...

```
import time
print("Hello M8!")
time.sleep(5)
```

`window.py` will be the script that takes the input as that is the one that has the window.

Comment: Hey, you've made a typo in my name :P

Comment: That's what I get for not using copy and paste :D

Comment: hehehehhehe No worries.